# What are some studies about the optimal diet plan for muscle building?

Tags: muscle, diet, bodybuilding, protein

Most fitness magazines and sites advise to eat 6 times per day and consume huge amounts of protein, usually 1 gram per pound, but I have seen suggestions like 2-3 grams per pound which is way too much.

Personally I have estimated my maximum muscle growth potential to be about 90kg at 12% body fat and I have almost achieved my maximum mass potential, since I am 87 kg at 12% body fat and 1.78 m height, without dieting at all.
In fact I only eat 2 times a day and my protein intake I would estimate to be around 50-60g per day and that makes me a little bit suspicious about the studies concerning bodybuilding diets.

A large amount of such studies and fitness magazines are funded by supplement companies so the information given is questionable.

So are there any studies conducted about the optimal diet for muscle growth that are not funded by supplement companies?
Can you provide papers or links?

Comment: Nutrition studies are usually pretty weak anyway as it's pretty hard to have strict adherence over long periods etc. You can find studies to back up basically any diet if you look hard enough.

Comment: Citation needed on "A large amount of such studies are funded by supplement companies so the information given is questionable."

Comment: Closed pending elaboration from OP.